# Pseudoinverse of a large sparse matrix in r

Tags: sparse-matrix, svd, r

This question was moved from Cross-Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274042/pseudoinverse-of-large-sparse-matrix-in-r

I am trying to calculate the pseudoinverse of a large sparse matrix in R using the singular value decomposition. The matrix is roughly 240,000 x 240,000, and I have it stored as type `dgCMatrix`. I have tried using `pinv`, `ginv`, and other standard pseudoinverse functions, but they error out due to memory constraints. I then tried to opt for the sparse matrix svd provided by the package `irlba`, which I was then going to use to compute the pseudoinverse using the standard formula after converting all outputs to sparse matrices. My code is here:

```
lim = 40
digits = 4
SVD =irlba(L,lim)
tU = round(SVD$u,digits)
nonZeroU = which(abs(U)>0,arr.ind = T)
sparseU = sparseMatrix(i=nonZeroU[,2],j=nonZeroU[,1],x = U[nonZeroU])
V = round(SVD$v,digits)
nonZeroV = which(abs(V)>0,arr.ind = T)
sparseV = sparseMatrix(i=nonZeroV[,1],j=nonZeroV[,2],x = U[nonZeroV])
D = as(Diagonal(x=1/SVD$d),"sparseMatrx")
pL =D%*%sparseU
pL = sparseV%*%pL
```

I am able to get to the last line without an issue, but then I get an error due to memory constraints that says

```
Error in sparseV %*% pL : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Of course I could piece together the pseudoinverse entry by entry using a for loop and vector multiplications, but I would like to be able to calculate it using a simple function that takes advantage of the sparsity of the resultant pseudoinverse matrix. Due to the nature of the original matrix (it is a graph laplacian), I know that the pseudoinverse should also be a sparse matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How sparse is your matrix, how sparse do you expect the pseudoinverse to be? A dense 240000^2 matrix of 4 byte numbers requires more than 200GB for storage, let alone for handling. Also, in many cases the inverse of a sparse matrix ends up being a dense matrix.

Comment: The matrix is very sparse-- <1%. The matrix L is a graph laplacian, so I expect the pseudoinverse to be equally sparse (I am saying this from empirical observation but haven't proven it yet)

Comment: Why do you expect the inverse of a Laplacian to be sparse? That's normally not true.

Comment: Do you really need the inverse/pseudoinverse matrix? For your use, you have considered the possibility of solving the linear system for applying the inverse transformation?

Comment: If you need to the pseudo inverse in order to apply it to a different matrix or vector, then you can use Krylov methods instead of computing the pseudo inverse explicitly. That way, you'll only have sparse matrix multiplication.

Comment: Well I am only saying that from empirical observation of a smaller subset of the data. Perhaps it is because the average degree of the graph is only around 2.5? Probably also highly disconnected if I had to guess

Comment: I am working on an implementation of the online learning algorithm of Herbster et al, which technically only requires one row of the pseudoinverse at a time. But one of the main advantages of the method is that the pseudoinverse can be calculated as a preprocessing step, and besides I was hoping to characterize it as a matrix

Comment: If the earlier steps work well, can't you keep the matrix in factored form, evaluating matrix-vector products one at a time, like $V(D(Ux))$? Also, $L^{+}_{ij}$ has an interpretation in terms of the resistivity distance between $i$ and $j$, so I expect that for any connected component of the graph $L^{+}$ would be dense. Do you have a specific reason for thinking it would be sparse here?

Comment: The error specifically comes from `nzmax > INT_MAX` (which is $2^31-1$), here: https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/blob/master/CHOLMOD/Core/cholmod_dense.c#L103